# Creating Funnel Chart in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibezierpath

Need to create Custom control for Funnel Chart in iOS ( Either in Swift or Objective - C ) .

Found Few library for it : here is link : https://github.com/ayudasystems/funnel

Planning to use BezierPath to implement Funnel Chart .

Kindly suggest the **Data Structure** which needs to implement this control .

**Note - Search lot of post but dint find the exact solution to implement Funnel chart in ios ( few posts are there but answers are not correct or accepted)

Comment: if you have the code sample, you should also have the code used to genrate that.

Comment: its cocoapod library so dint accessed much functionality , after going through these i m creating control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You have to use simple **logic** to implement above funnel chart.

There are 5 items : *A1,A2,A3,A4,A5*  and *funnel* is height of **200**.

&&  *A1=30% ,A2=25% , A3=20%, A4=15% and A5=10%*

```
Now distritribute items according to height % in funnel. So

A1 = 0.3*200  = 60
A2 = 0.25*200 = 50
A3 = 0.2*200  = 40
A4 = 0.15*200 = 30
A5 = 0.1*200  = 20
--------------------
Total         = 200


On the basis of above calculated height:- 5 different BezierPath can  be drawn . 

Above data can be generalised to 'n' items and 'x' Height .
```

Logic to **Calculate height Distribution**

```
class HeightDistribution {
   class func  height(percentages: [Float] , TotalHeight:Float ) -> [Float]  
      {
        var heights = [Float]()
        for percentage in   percentages
        {
           let height = (percentage/100)*TotalHeight
            heights.append(height)
        }
        return heights
    }
}
```

[Progress Demo Funnel Chart app || Swift3](https://github.com/shrawan2015/Application-Demo-StackOverFlow/tree/master/FunnelChartDemo)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Data Structure' should be simple: an array of values between 0.0 and 100.0, each value representing either a horizontal rectangular band, or a trapezoid for the funnel part, with an indicator to show where it changes from rectangles to trapezoids, plus colours for each of the segments.

Start simple, and then go on to embellish the picture, with gaps between the segments, shadows, and so on.  Having made a static version, you should then be able to transfer to layers to obtain animation.